# Inbox notification text can't be found in linked question

Tags: support, notifications

Recently I asked a question and got one answer:

[OData: get entity by key but without entity set name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041286/odata-get-entity-by-key-but-without-entity-set-name/55057968)

Not any comments. But in my mailbox in the top menu bar I can see the text that is not found on the question page.

[image]

Where can I find the text encircled in red?

> No, this is not possible as this is against the basic standard laid
>   down by OASIS

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't, directly. Someone posted an answer, and later edited it.

If you check the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55057968/revisions) for that answer, you'll find that text on the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55057968/1):

> [image: revision changes]

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55057968/revisions) on the answer posted by Shivam Sharma, we can see that the text you saw in the notification was the original text of the answer. It was later edited to its current text.